# How to navigate from one Stack navigator to other in React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

Here is my code I have multiple Stack.navigators. I want to navigate from one Stack.Navigator to other.I have to navigate  From Login Screen to Profile screen

```
<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={Routes.PROFILE} screenOptions={noHeader}>
    <Stack.Screen name={Routes.PROFILE} component={Profile} />
    <Stack.Screen name={Routes.Home} component={Home} />
  </Stack.Navigator>


<Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={Routes.LOGIN} screenOptions={noHeader}>
    <Stack.Screen name={Routes.LOGIN} component={Login} />
    <Stack.Screen name={Routes.SIGNUP} component={SIGNUP} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
```

If I try  navigation.navigate('Profile') am getting error
ERROR  The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"Profile"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'Profile'?

If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator.

This is a development-only warning and won't be shown in production.

Comment: Have you followed the the link? It will help you!

Comment: I have followed link.but there is no where mentioned how to navigate from one navigator to other

Comment: `navigation.navigate('Root', { screen: 'Settings' });`

Answer (score 0):

As @devpolo mentioned; first you have to define your route as screen in other stack.

```
     function Root() {
          return (
            <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={Routes.PROFILE} screenOptions={noHeader}>
            <Stack.Screen name={Routes.PROFILE} component={Profile} />
            <Stack.Screen name={Routes.Home} component={Home} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
          );
        }
    
        function Navigation(){
        return(
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={Routes.LOGIN} screenOptions={noHeader}>
            <Stack.Screen name={Routes.LOGIN} component={Login} />
            <Stack.Screen name={Routes.SIGNUP} component={SIGNUP} />
            <Stack.Screen name={'Root'} component={Root} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
         )
       }
```

Then you can navigate between nesting navigators with:

```
navigation.navigate('Root', { screen: Routes.PROFILE });
```